# Denodo Json Source and Base View: how to make VQL more traditional SQL syntax

Tags: denodo

I have a web service api

In Denodo, I have virtualized the following api:

```
https://delphi.cmu.edu/epidata/fluview/?regions=nat&epiweeks=201501,201601,201701
```

as

```
https://delphi.cmu.edu/epidata/fluview/?regions=@{regions}&epiweeks=@{epiweeks}
```

This allows us, in Denodo, to write the following:

```
Select * from bv_fluview where epiweeks = '201501,201601,201701' and regions = 'nat'
```

Is there any way where the query could be written in a more traditional way such as:

```
   Select * from bv_fluview where epiweeks in ('201501','201601','201701') and regions = 'nat'
```

I am relatively new to Denodo.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Denodo, you can use the IN clause to check if a value is present in a list

```
SELECT * 
FROM bv_fluview 
WHERE epiweeks IN ('201501','201601','201701') 
AND regions = 'nat'
```

This would return the same result as your original query but with a more conventional syntax for the IN operator.

Comment: yes, it does indeed work.  the execution plan shows that it translated into multiple calls and then union the results.  so it works, but would be slightly slower.